# Get row instead of column when using MIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL query, since I'm trying to retrieve multiple columns (or the whole row) when using `MIN()` at a joined table column.

I'll try to make my question more clear with an example, I left out a lot of joins and stuff that aren't necessary:

```
SELECT
    product.*,
    MIN(stock.qty)
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    stock ON product.id = stock.id
GROUP BY
    product.id
```

The result I'm getting is now the whole product row, and the `stock.qty` column, but I want to retrieve the whole `stock` row of the entry with the least qty.
This probably can't be accomplished using `MIN()`, but my question is, how can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Here's an SQL fiddle for some more explanation:

You'll see here that `Product A` joins the qty of stock item `2`, which is correct, it's 10, the other stock item of product A is 15. But, I also want to retrieve the `backorders` field **of that same row**, which is `1`, but my query returns `0` as backorder, which is from stock row `1`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b232e/3/0

Comment: whole stock row based on min(qty) for that product ?

Comment: Yes. I could retrieve the stock.id now, but that isn't necessarily the id of the stock row with the least qty.

Comment: What happens if a product has the same minimum qty twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    product.*,
    s1.*
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    stock s1 ON product.id = s1.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    stock s2 ON product.id = s2.product_id AND s1.qty > s2.qty
WHERE
    s2.qty IS NULL
```

Supposing there is only one minimal quantity stock per product. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b232e/7

OR http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2d89/3

```
SELECT
    product.*,
    s1.*
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    stock s1 ON product.id = s1.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    stock s2 ON product.id = s2.product_id
        AND (s1.qty > s2.qty or (s1.qty = s2.qty and s1.id > s2.id))
WHERE
    s2.qty IS NULL
```

If two stocks are minimal for one product, then pick the one with smaller ID.

Comment: This looks good, but I actually left a join in my question, for the sake of readability, but I can't seem to get it to work _with_ this join, I get an empty result set. This is a adjusted fiddle from my original question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0cb/5 - and this is that fiddle, adjusted with your suggestions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0cb/9 (qty 15 for product A, should be 10). Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: Well, with subproducts it it becomes a bit convoluted - with that join you get product rows "multiplied" by subproducts, so you actually have two rows for product A, one for each subproduct, but by doing group by product id, you again collapse them to one and get "random" values. It is not clear what behaviour you expect in this case - you have stock defined only for subproducts, so you want get one product and its subproduct with smallest stock? or zeroes for product stock and proper minima for subproduts stocks ?

Comment: I want 1 subproduct for each product, the one with the smallest stock. Of that subproduct, I need the whole row, not only the qty amount. It's possible that a product has no subproducts, of those I just want the original product in my result.

Comment: @MaikelKoek not pretty: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a4fa/3 - would be probably more usable as two queries (might use UNION to return as one). The indirection of subtype makes it weird. And not sure what happens (and if it is even allowed in your data) if product has subtypes but also stock on its own.. It will probably be shown once for minimal subtype and once for own stock.. It seems best would be to introduce "trivial" subtype for each type which currently does not have its own, to make the schema behave the same way for both cases.

Comment: That looks terrible indeed. ;) For resolving my problem, I created a second query now. May not be perfect, but it was the fastest solution in the end. All this weird joins don't seem perfect either. I'll mark your answer as correct, since it helped me the most, and was actually a good answer for my original question, without the extra join! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
  name,
  stock.id,
  s.product_id,
  qty,
  backorders
    FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN (stock
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
        MIN(qty) q,
        s.product_id
      FROM stock s
      GROUP BY s.product_id) s
      ON s.q = stock.qty
      AND s.product_id = stock.product_id)
    ON p.id = s.product_id
```

Comment: I don't see why I should add a `group by` of a `stock` field.. I get a single row with this query, but it only contains `stock.qty`. I want more columns of the same row from where that qty came from.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst MySQL let's you arbitrarily return *a* value from the grouped table, a better approach would to go down the subquery route, to join back to the data, so something like:

```
SELECT      p.*,
            s.qty,
            s.backorders

FROM (
    SELECT      MIN(stock.qty) AS qty,
                stock.product_id

    FROM        stock

    GROUP BY    stock.product_id
) minstock

INNER JOIN  stock s
    ON      minstock.product_id = s.product_id
    AND     minstock.qty = s.qty

RIGHT JOIN  product p
    ON      p.id = s.product_id
```

Now, if there are multiple rows sharing the same minimum stock for a particular product, they will all come back, but you will see the backorder count for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* 
     , s.*
  FROM product p
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM stock x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT product_id
                   , MIN(stock.qty) min_qty
                FROM stock
               GROUP
                  BY product_id
            ) y
           ON y.product_id = x.product_id
          AND y.min_qty = x.qty
     ) s
    ON s.product_id = p.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b232e/13